# How to set different alignment for TextField hint and the actual text value?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this `TextField`:

[image: Hint]

As you see this is the hint of my `TextField`, aligned at right.

The problem is that when I type something inside the `TextField`, I want that value to be written from the left, but actually, it's written on the right also:

[image: TextField value]

I want the hint to stay aligned, but when I type something, it goes to another side of `TextField`.

The code I'm trying:

```
TextField(
  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try with `Directionality` widget, if not give a try

Comment: Hi, yes I did tried it, and it force the alignment for both the hint and the actual value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
TextField(
  textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    …
  ),
),
```

Comment: it does work,  tried setting wrapping the `TextField` widget with `Directionality` and setting `textDirection` and it force aligning both text and hint , but setting it directly in the `TextField` get me there, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Create this variable to keep text aligned:

```
TextAlign textAlign = TextAlign.right;
```

In the `onChange` method add:

```
onChanged: (val) {
  if (val.isNotEmpty){
    setState(() {
      textAlign = TextAlign.left;
    });
  } else {
    setState(() {
      textAlign = TextAlign.right;
    });
  }
},
```

Finally, add this to your text field:

```
TextField(
  textAlign: textAlign,
);
```

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your answer, but I don't want to manage this by the state since onChanged is triggered when writing, or deleting letters.